# Delete specific named TextBox in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I have a PowerPoint presentation which have about 105 slides. On each slide, there is a Text Box named TextBox4. I want to delete all these text boxes.

I have tried some VBA code by Google Search. But that doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with VBA regarding this.

Comment: Could you please update the code to understand better

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I know it very well. Thank you very much. But what if you share knowledge instead of just suggesting me how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean an ActiveX textbox like so:

[image]

You could use the following VBA code to loop through every sheet and delete the text box.

```
Sub DeleteTextBox()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim PPSlide As Slide
    For Each PPSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        PPSlide.Shapes("TextBox4").Delete
    Next
End Sub
```